# IIS is executing request even if CORS is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two MVC ASP.NET applications. I'm trying to make ajax POST request from one app to another. By default CORS should have been disabled, and I'm getting alert in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2211/Home/Form. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2282' is therefore not allowed access.

So everything should be right. But...

I realized that this request executed that specific action on http://localhost:2211. How is that possible? Why that request was executed even though CORS had been disabled?

Comment: CORS is a mixture of client and server side - the request _hasn't_ been executed.  It got as far as the server, which then said no.

Comment: That message is from the client browser, refusing to connect to a different location. How have you disabled CORS?

Comment: @JamesThorpe request has been executed. The action changes one value in database. And that value has been changed to the new one which was in the request.
@Adrian actually I didn't do nothing. But because response didn't have 
any `access-control` header, I assumed CORS was disabled.

Comment: TIL, CORS doesn't stop the request, it stops the response being used if the header isn't there or the accept doesn't cover the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request to `http://localhost:2211/Home/Form` was made, however the *response* from that request did not contain an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header which results in the browser declining to process the response for you.

Until the server responds to the request that's been made to it, providing the header, the browser won't know if the request was/is permitted or not, i.e. the onus is on the *browser* to react to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, rather than the server.

You may even see different behaviours here depending on the browser you're using as, for example:

> Internet Explorer does not consider the port when comparing origins.

[*learn.microsoft.com > What is "same origin"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#what-is-same-origin)

Comment: What is the best way to block all requests from domains that are not available on my white list then? By manually checking `Origin` header?

Comment: @user3609885, pretty much! Unfortunately you aren't given any surety that will actually work, which I suspect is why the onus is on the browser to check and implement CORS checking. I (read: anyone!) could write an app that makes a request to your server and spoofs the `Origin`. Because CORS works the way it does, if you don't want your server-side code to run when called from an "un-trusted" origin, it's not the right solution for you.

Comment: As far as I know you are not allowed to change `Origin` header, or 
you meant change raw data on packets layer? But it's possible only when you are using http instead of https? The best way is just to use some kind of anti forgery tokens or authentication systems? Am I right?

Comment: @user3609885, sorry for the late response, you (as a web browser) may not be able to change some headers, but if you've written an app that makes requests to URLs, you can send whatever headers you want in the request. If the code can't / shouldn't execute without the caller being authorised to do so, then authentication and authorisation is the way to go! =)